# Arrow Function React Component different from "equivalent" counterpart

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following a tutorial and I am getting confused with my arrow version of it and their function version. 
I have a LoaderButton.js and I can write the component as a normal functional component or an arrow component:

Functional Component:

```
export default function LoaderButton({
  isLoading,
  className = "",
  disabled = false,
  ...props
}) {
  return (
    <Button
      className={`LoaderButton ${className}`}
      disabled={disabled || isLoading}
      {...props}
    >
      {isLoading && <Glyphicon glyph="refresh" className="spinning" />}
      {props.children}
    </Button>
  );
}
```

Arrow Component:

```
const LoaderButton = (
  isLoading,
  className = "",
  disabled = false,
  ...props ) => (
    <Button
      className={`LoaderButton ${className}`}
      disabled={disabled || isLoading}
      {...props}
    >
      {isLoading && <Glyphicon glyph="refresh" className="spinning" />}
      {props.children}
    </Button>
  )


export default LoaderButton
```

And the LoaderButton is imported and used here in my Login.js:

```
export default function Login() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { userHasAuthenticated } = useAppContext();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [fields, handleFieldChange] = useFormFields({
    email: "",
    password: ""
  });

  function validateForm() {
    return fields.email.length > 0 && fields.password.length > 0;
  }

  async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      await Auth.signIn(fields.email, fields.password);
      userHasAuthenticated(true);
      history.push("/");
    } catch (e) {
      onError(e);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="Login">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <FormGroup controlId="email" bsSize="large">
          <ControlLabel>Email</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            autoFocus
            type="email"
            value={fields.email}
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup controlId="password" bsSize="large">
          <ControlLabel>Password</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="password"
            value={fields.password}
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <LoaderButton
          block
          type="submit"
          bsSize="large"
          isLoading={isLoading}
          disabled={!validateForm()}
        >
          Login
        </LoaderButton>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The standard functional component works as expected.

But the arrow function component seems to have `isLoading` stuck to true 
AND gets this error:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `disabled` of type `object` supplied to `Button`, expected `boolean`.
```

I thought arrow function components were supposed to be a simpler way to write function components.

I keep thinking it has to do with binding and therefore it's somehow binding the props I have different but I can't find any information on the differences of their bindings. I thought if my Login.js is binding according to the way it's written then I should be fine?

I honestly would prefer to write using an arrow function syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't *quite* equivalent. You didn't destructure props correctly. Wrap all the props with `{}` so your functional component is taking a single `props` argument.

```
const LoaderButton = ({
  isLoading,
  className = "",
  disabled = false,
  ...props
}) => (
  <Button
    className={`LoaderButton ${className}`}
    disabled={disabled || isLoading}
    {...props}
  >
    {isLoading && <Glyphicon glyph="refresh" className="spinning" />}
    {props.children}
  </Button>
);

export default LoaderButton
```

Comment: Ah, wow duh! So was it reading `disabled = false, ...props` ?

Comment: @KyleCalica-St No, `isLoading` is the first argument. React would read *that* as "props" and ignore the rest.